# (perhaps) A Stupid Question about Poker

Tags: probability, combinatorics

first time to ask a question here so I hope this would be an interesting one.

Suppose me and a friend of mine are playing poker (1 vs 1), and at a certain time during the heads up we get bored and decide to go all in every hand without looking at our cards until a winner is declared.

We suppose (of course) that before dealing cards the change of one of of us winning the all in is perfect equal: 0.5 me and 0.5 my friend.

BUT we starts the heads up with different stacks, say that I start with P percentage of the total chips in play, and my friend have 1-P percentage of the chip in play.
So the question here is : what is the probability of me winning the heads up??

My first answer that I think it's correct is : P.
I made the calculations for a particular case in which i start the heads up with 80 and my friend with 20 and came out that my chance of winning are exactly 0.8.

I attached a photo with my solution (hope the graph it's clear and the calculations also : the chance of winning the first time is 0.5, the second time 0.25 and then with probability 1/16 we return to initial stacks which is the top of the tree which i marked with a star)

Hope you guys like the question and thank you in advance for the help

[image]

Comment: Not sure everyone here understands the rules of the game.  How does your current stake alter the chance of winning?

Comment: sorry my fault: what I was meaning is that the probability of winning  the heads up at the second all in is 0.25 (lose the first all in an then win the second one ) and then with probability 1/16 we return the initial situation.

Comment: You may find the "Problem of Points" interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points

Comment: Thank you awkward. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be about poker anymore. It looks more like a stupid coin-tossing game.

You're correct, but it takes more than just calculating separate examples to prove that. I'll assume that coins are indefinitely splittable.

Assume that we have the probability $p(x)$ for winning where $x$ is the amount of the total coins you have. You have certainly that $p(1)=1$ and $p(0)=0$ (since you've already won or lost in those cases). Furthermore if we consider your stack after a single toss:

$$\begin{matrix}
& \text{win} & \text{loose} \\
\hline
x \le 1/2 & 2x & 0 \\
x \ge 1/2 & 1  & 2x - 1 \\
\end{matrix}$$

This means that we can see that this gives us a way to give $p(x)$ certain properties. If $x\le1/2$ the chance of winning is $1/2$ of the chance of winning with $2x$ of stack (as you have $1/2$ chance of reaching that in the next toss and otherwise you loose). We can do similar calculation for $x\ge 1/2$ and get (and of course the $p(1/2) = 1/2$ by symmetry):

$$p(x) = \begin{cases}
p(2x)/2 & \text{ if } x < 1/2 \\
1/2 & \text { if } x = 1/2 \\
1/2 + p(2x-1)/2 & \text{ if } x > 1/2 \\
\end{cases}$$

We can immediately see that $p(x)=x$ would satisfy that condition.

To see that this is indeed the only solution one would note that this property of $p$ could be used to determine $p(j2^{-k})$ recursively and that $p(j2^{-k}) = j2^{-k}$. Then you can also see from the property that $p(x)$ is continuous and since we have proven that $p(x)=x$ on a dense set then $p(x)=x$ always.

---

Another way is to consider how the table looks if you express $x$ in binary. $2x$ means to shift the bits one step to the left and so does $2x-1$ except that one discards the most significant (fractional) bit. In your example you would have $x = 0.8_{(10)} = 0.110011001100\dots_{(2)}$. Those are the tosses that makes the game continue. The probability for a win is when the left most fractional bit is $1$ and the toss ends the game which has the probability $2^{-j}$ for the $j$th toss. This means that you in the example can win on the first or second toss, the fifth or sixth etc.

Comment: Wow thank you skyking for your answer. The answer is completely different from what I was thinking! by the way my calculations in the photo was only for give an input for the solution to someone. Do you think that there may also be a more " combinatorial" answer to this problem?? Thank you again for your answer

Comment: @paolopazzo I don't think it's much of an combinatorial problem. Unless the stacks are equally divided there's one outcome that will end the game (the player with the larger stack winning) and one that will let it continue (the player with the smaller stack winning).